Is this a good idea of optimizing the number of predictors in my model?
My task in a uni project is to predict a binary response variable based on a number of difficult to interpret features.
The method used is logistic regression (without a penalty). I have noticed that adding some second-order polynomial terms improve the performance of the model. However, I think that including all such terms is unnecessary and might lead to overfitting.
I have applied forward variable selection in two ways: firstly, sequentially adding the variable that minimizes the AIC, and secondly, using SequentialFeatureSelector from scikit-learn.
I evaluated the models using cross-validation with 5 folds and by calculating the AIC on the fitted data. This resulted in graphs of the following form:

Now I wish to pick the model which minimizes the AIC without compromizing accuracy (in this case 22 variables picked by forward selection).
Is this a good method of model selection? Are there more standardized ways of doing this?

Your description sounds like you are reinventing forward stepwise selection.  See the results of this search for extensive commentary on that approach.

An additional problem is that you seem to be using accuracy as your measure of model performance, which isn't a good idea. To get useful help on how to proceed, please edit the question to say more about your study: in particular, how many cases in your data are in the minority outcome class and the nature of the predictor variables (categorical, continuous, ...). Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies is a good guide on accepted ways to deal with multiple predictors, including chapters on logistic regression.

Thank you! I'll definitely check out the book! My course was very confusing and went through a lot of models in statistical learning without actually giving us tools to evaluate results...

In short: No, usually it is a bad idea to optimise the number of predictors in a model.
Using model regularisation is much more prudent. CV.SE has two excellent threads on the topic: Algorithms for automatic model selection and Stepwise AIC - Does there exist controversy surrounding this topic? which I would suggest you read carefully.
To move you forward in your particular case: instead of using LogisticRegression without l2 (or some other loss) penalty start by selecting the appropriate level of $L_2$ regularisation via CV. (and remember we need to have our variables in the same scale when we regularise)
There might be cases that we need to do some "strong" variable selection (e.g. cost of collecting certain data features) but that is not the case often.

Nicely summarized (+1). I suspect that the OP might also make use of the "data reduction" methods explained by Frank Harrell in Section 4.7 of RMS, to cut down on the number of effective predictors without reference to the outcomes.

Thank you for your input,
I tried implementing an L_2 penalized model using gridsearch and cross validation scores (f2 and accuracy, 5 folds) to find the optimal value for the cost parameter C.
However, this resulted in a very small value for C (C=0.08 compared with the default C=1 in sklearn.LogisticRegression). This made me afraid of model overfitting which is why I tried to implement stepwise selection.
Should I go with the value I got for C instead? The number of parameters in the model would be 67 and I have 255 and 256 observations of the respective categories Y=0, Y=1.

Ohh, I just read up about L_2 regularization and C=0.08 implies a stronger regularization than C=1.0 facepalm
This makes me much more confident in the grid search method. Do you have any suggestions about what cross-validation scoring I should use when searching for the cost parameter?

The choice of cross-validation methods has to depend on your data and the stability of your resulting estimates. Without knowing more, it is hard to say which is right. I personally use repeated-CV $5 \times 5$ as my starting point.
